# SQL Join only returning 1 row

Tags: mysql, join

Not quite sure what I'm missing, but my SQL statement is only returning one row.

```
  SELECT 
    tl.*, 
    (tl.topic_total_rating/tl.topic_rates) as topic_rating, 
    COUNT(pl.post_id) - 1 as reply_count, 
    MIN(pl.post_time) AS topic_time, 
    MAX(pl.post_time) AS topic_bump 
  FROM topic_list tl 
    JOIN post_list pl 
      ON tl.topic_id=pl.post_parent 
    WHERE 
      tl.topic_board_link = %i 
      AND topic_hidden != 1 
    ORDER BY %s
```

I have two tables (post_list and topic_list), and post_list's post_parent links to a topic_list's topic_id.

Instead of returning all the topics (where their board's topic_board_link is n), it only returns one topic.

Comment: post relevant parts of CREATE TABLE, including PK/FK definitions.

Comment: PK of post_list is post_id, PK of topic_list is topic_id. I don't (I think) have any FKs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would normally need a GROUP BY clause in there.  MySQL has different rules from Standard SQL on the subject of when GROUP BY is needed.  This is therefore closer to Standard SQL:

```
SELECT tl.*, 
       (tl.topic_total_rating/tl.topic_rates) AS topic_rating, 
       COUNT(pl.post_id) - 1 AS reply_count, 
       MIN(pl.post_time) AS topic_time, 
       MAX(pl.post_time) AS topic_bump 
  FROM topic_list AS tl 
  JOIN post_list  AS pl ON tl.topic_id = pl.post_parent 
 WHERE tl.topic_board_link = ?   -- %i
   AND tl.topic_hidden != 1 
 GROUP BY tl.col1, ..., topic_rating
 ORDER BY ?   -- %s
```

In Standard SQL, you would have to list every column in topic_list, plus the non-aggregate value topic_rating (and you might have to list the expression rather than the display label or column alias in the select list).

You also have a restriction condition on 'topic_board_link' which might be limiting your result set to one group.  You cannot normally use a placeholder in the ORDER BY clause, either.

Comment: Thanks, the GROUP BY saved the day. I should probably pick up a book on SQL again ;)